# fair processing for parallel jobs with job priority using spring batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, bpmn, camunda

Am creating a spring/camunda bpmn app where multiple processes of the same type will be running simultaneously and each one has a queue of messages to be processed. Also there will be prioritisation for jobs, the rules are as follows:

- if all jobs have the same priority then they will be processed
  simultaneously and with the same load from each.
- If a higher priority job is started then it will be processed faster than other jobs but
  without blocking them.
- There is a limit for the overall sent messages per second that should not be exceeded

Can someone help design/figure out this problem?

Comment: I do not get your use case .... what do you mean by "simultaneously running instance with a queue each"? The line between batch and process does not seem clear.

Comment: Each job is a bulksms job meaning it will have a huge number of messages to be sent but not all at once so they are a queue of messages to be processed